# Can I use the first page of a PDF document as its alias icon in OS X?

Tags: macos, pdf, desktop, icons, alias

Is there a painless method for using the first page of a PDF as its alias icon in OS X? The operating system does this for PDF documents on the desktop, and I'd like to replicate the behavior for aliases. I have many PDF books stored in my [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com), and I have aliases to those that I'm currently reading on my desktop. Having icons associated with the aliases would make it much easier to differentiate between books without having to read many titles.

Can this be done without manually creating an icon from the PDF page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [hardlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) instead of alias, it will solve icon problem. If you are ok with Terminal: just run `ln path/to/your/file.pdf ~/Desktop` this will create hardlink to your pdf on the Desktop, if not: I can't find any other gui for such thing, but I can share [my little app](http://www.2shared.com/file/VzMRjECI/createLinkapp.html) (droplet running Applescript, I need to rewrite it some day :) )

Comment: @rbright: you should vote up the answer if you found it helpful. +1